# Need SQL to remove data where it matches with other table field but only before a given date

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have an access database which is currently removing all rows where the field CP is found within a seperate table CPExcl (within CP column). However, I want to change this so it only removes this in circumstances where it matches the CPExcl table and is before 9/5/2012.
I have written the following code, which brings about no results:

```
[CP] not in (select distinct [CP] from CPExcl) 
AND ([CP] in (select distinct [CP] from CPExcl) 
AND LUD >9/5/2012);
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Josh

Answer (score 0):

"However, I want to change this so it only removes this in circumstances where it matches the CPExcl table **and** is before **9/5/2012**"

And before you delete, try to SELECT it first:

```
([CP] not in (select distinct [CP] from CPExcl) 
AND LUD < #9/5/2012#) -- before 9/5/2012. so change it to less than
OR ([CP] in (select distinct [CP] from CPExcl)
```

IIRC, Access' Date type uses pound sign(#). So change this 9/5/2012 to #9/5/2012#; otherwise that will become integer

And there's no need to use DISTINCT. IN/NOT IN automatically apply distinct on related query.

```
([CP] not in (select [CP] from CPExcl) 
AND LUD < #9/5/2012#) -- before 9/5/2012. so change it to less than
OR ([CP] in (select [CP] from CPExcl)
```

**EDIT**

"'I want everything where CP isnt in column CP in CPExcl' however I also want those where 'CP is in the CP Column of CPExcl and where the LUD is 9 May 2012"

```
[CP] not in (select [CP] from CPExcl) 
OR
(
    [CP] in (select [CP] from CPExcl) 
    AND LUD < #9/5/2012# -- before 9/5/2012. so change it to less than
)
```

You can short-circuit that to this:

```
[CP] not in (select [CP] from CPExcl) 
OR
LUD < #9/5/2012# -- before 9/5/2012. so change it to less than
```

As a precaution, SELECT before you DELETE, check if the logic fits the problem. Happy Coding! ツ

Comment: You have switched it here. So I want it to say 'I want everything where CP isnt in column CP in CPExcl' however I also want those where 'CP is in the CP Column of CPExcl and where the LUD is 9 May 2012 or later'